# (using MySQL insert) can't find the id of record when it exists

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Using PHP I'm inserting a record in a MySQL database. If the record is new I get the insert_id but if it already exists I can't get the id using a single query.

Both of the following queries allow me to add the record or skip if it already exists:

```
INSERT INTO `emails` (`email`) VALUE ('abc@example.com') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id`=`id`

INSERT IGNORE INTO `emails` (`email`) VALUE ('abc@example.com')
```

What is the right way to get the right result in both cases?

**EDIT:** Here's my table syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE `emails` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that it's the value of LAST_INSERT_ID that ends up in insert_id.

Quote from the MySQL manual;

To make LAST_INSERT_ID() meaningful for updates, insert rows as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c=3;
```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: This is will only work if data is actually updated. If no data is changed, he's in the same boat as before.

Comment: I like this answer **except** that we need to know what the purpose of this application is. If it's, say, user registration, changing `id` could cause big problems (i.e., one should check to see if the email address exists *before* trying to insert anything and changing existing data). Still, +1 since I learned something :)

Comment: Thanks but I should agree with msanford.

Comment: This way the last insert id gets incremented without any purpose so although no new record is added, I can't get the **next** available id for the next insert query. Some are simply skipped.

Comment: @webbiedave The line above will set LAST_INSERT_ID correctly even if the "c=3" is removed, ie. nothing is updated except id is set to itself.

Comment: This does NOT change the id, it only sets it. And it WILL run when nothing is updated. All in all, a good answer. See also the small example at http://pastebin.com/5RHXkuM2

Comment: @msanford The statement does not actually change the id of the record, it just updates LAST_INSERT_ID() to the id of the existing row.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson create a new e-mail address and query that, it's inserted in db. query the same thing 3 more times, nothing happens in db. change the e-mail address and requery. First record gets id 1 and the second one gets id 5.

Comment: @inhan I can't repeat your problem, am I understanding it wrong? http://pastebin.com/pgrZDeKU

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I'm updating my question to add the create syntax for my table. Does that result the same?

Comment: No, with InnoDB you're getting the holes in the ID sequence. This is because InnoDB will allocate an id for the insert which never happens, and InnoDB never reuses allocated ids. This is exactly the same behavior as if you start a transaction, do a regular insert and roll back. Is a hole in the sequence a problem?

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Never came across this issue so the information you gave was so valuable. I think I'll go about using 2 queries.